# Heroku JawsDB max user connection

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I am trying to use the JawsDB Maria with spring boot application on Heroku.

I always got the error when trying to create the connection, not only the program but also the sql browser.

The error as below:

> User '-----' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10)

Does anybody know why ?

Where can I check who create the connections and can I close the connections ?

Comment: hey mate, I am facing the same problem... JawsDB with free plan. It is saying the same thing. How did you close those connections?

Comment: I decrease the connection to only 2

Answer (score 0):

Checking for disconnect -- that requires looking at the user's code.

Do you have "connection pooling" turned on?  What are the parameters associated with it?

Comment: I have set with these, spring.datasource.max-active: 2 and spring.datasource.max-idle: 2, don't know it's enough or not?

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the plan you are using probably has limit of maximum connection. Either you upgrade your plan or use connection pooling to limit the number of connection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the number of connections to the database by your account.

- Limit your application connection pool size if applicable
- Remember to close all other clients that are connected to the database, e.g. Mysql Workbench.